# How can I use an input without interfering with the user text input? Context: Socket based Chat - Python 3.9

Tags: python, io, console-application, console.log, python-sockets

## Context:

I'm writing some Python scripts to build a realtime chat using sockets. I got to allow comunication, data flow and different message types and options. The problem is that the user needs a command input to operate the chat and everytime I call print() function, the text gets printed between the user input, nevertheless the user input keeps data integrity. What can I do to keep the user input clean all the time?

## Client script:

```py
def StablishConnection():
    ...

def SetConfiguration():
    ...

#  This one is for listening
def ListenServer():
    while True:
        global SERVER_SOCKET, BUFFER_SIZE
        try:
            data = SERVER_SOCKET.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode('utf-8')
            print(data)
        except Exception:
            pass

#  This one is for writing
def ChatRoutine():
    global SERVER_SOCKET, NICKNAME
    while True:
        try:
            mensaje = input(f'@{NICKNAME}: ')
            if not mensaje: continue
            SERVER_SOCKET.sendall(f'{MessageType.CONTENIDO_TEXTO.value}\{NICKNAME}\{mensaje}'.encode('utf-8'))
        except Exception:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        HOST = sys.argv[1]
    
    StablishConnection()
    SetConfiguration()

    writing = threading.Thread(target=ChatRoutine)
    writing.setDaemon(True)
    writing.start()
    
    listening = threading.Thread(target=ListenServer)
    listening.setDaemon(True)
    listening.start()
    listening.join()
```

I hope you could give some clue or something, I've struggling with this for about 2 days. Thank you all!!!

Comment: Use ncurses or tkinter so you can display the chat in a separate area of the screen than the input.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar!!! I googled about python curses and it is just what I'm looking for. Also I have a doubt, is there some offcial documentation with a tutorial or something like that? It seems like it's too basic, but it isn't, besides, no website or video that I found gets deeper enough into topic...

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about tutorials on it. Tkinter, which is graphical, is more common and you should be able to find more help on it.